# When Using Stokes Theorem, do you have to find the unit vector of the normal or just the normal?

Tags: calculus, stokes-theorem

I know how to apply Stokes' Theorem, but have seen some examples where they find the unit vector for the normal and don't know when this has to be done?
Thanks

Comment: Show a specific example that you have worked and have trouble dealing with

Comment: https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=4&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwi4xsar4cLMAhWLwY4KHZBXBCEQtwIILzAD&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.youtube.com%2Fwatch%3Fv%3DtyfZQ2NZfqo&usg=AFQjCNGbN98HxlJpkUzenfN7RZ65063Ouw&sig2=TRQc3141MFRPuUEW8zFvgA